# How can I arrange linear equation in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, algebra

How can I arrange linear equation in Mathematica
When I define

```
Subscript[R, 2] := Subscript[a, 2] t + Subscript[b, 2];
Subscript[R, 3] := Subscript[a, 3] t + Subscript[b, 3];
```

[image]
then

```
Expand[Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3]]
```

[image]

The result is constant a_2 behind t in eqation,  but I want the constant a_2 to be before t in the order of the equation. 
like this picture
[image]

Comment: Does `TraditionalForm` work for you?  It does output the $a_i$ and $b_i$ first within each monomial, which is what you explicitly asked for.  However, the terms are not ordered by decreasing power of $t$, or collected into a single coefficient (as in your picture.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask what many people asked before you in all kinds of variations. The answer is, yes it is possible, but it is not a simple matter. A deeper understanding of how Mathematica shows you expressions in the notebook (as formatted *boxes*) is required which is not obvious.

Nevertheless let me outline how it can work:

1. We take your poly which is a sum which means an expression of the form `Plus[monomial1, monomial2, ...]`.
2. We replace the `Plus` with our own operator `plus` that only *looks* like a sum. Inside `plus` we can define how Mathematica should sort the monomials.
3. We will wrap our *does only look like a sum* inside an `InterpretationBox` that ensures that you can use such a look-alike poly as input and it is again a real sum

Here we go:

```
plus /: MakeBoxes[plus[args__], form_] := With[
  {niceFormatting = 
    RowBox[Riffle[MakeBoxes[#, form] & /@ {args}, "+"]]}, 
  InterpretationBox[niceFormatting, Plus[args]]

Subscript[R, 2] := Subscript[a, 2] t + Subscript[b, 2];
Subscript[R, 3] := Subscript[a, 3] t + Subscript[b, 3];

poly = Expand[Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3]]

TraditionalForm[poly /. Plus :> plus]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or even

```
TeXForm[poly /. Plus :> plus]
```

$$a_2 a_3 t^2+a_3 b_2 t+a_2 b_3 t+b_2 b_3$$